# async Task Freezes When Calling EF Async Methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have a async method that returns an xml string.  When I add the task to a list of tasks, it starts the task but hangs on the first await when talking to the database using Entity Framework.  Below is the sample code.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GenerateXml(long id)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
    tasks.Add(GenerateXmlAsync(id));
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private async Task<string> GenerateXmlAsync(long id)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDatabaseContext())
    {
        var item = await dbContext.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync(itm => itm.Id = id);
        /* do some calculations, generate the xml... */
        var xml = "<generated by code above>";
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Using streaming logs on Azure, I can see that the task runs but never makes it past the dbContext async method.  Is there a reason why it would hang?

Comment: connection problems... can you debug it?

Comment: If I change `FirstOrDefaultAsync` to `FirstOrDefault` and remove `await`, it works fine.

Comment: Mandatory reference to avoid deadlocks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` is a blocking call. You are actively blocking the call. In fact, `GenerateXml` has *no* `await`s which means it will execute synchronously and the compiler will give you an error about it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is correct. You are creating a deadlock with `Task.WaitAll`. The UI thread is waiting for the `GenerateXmlAsync` to complete. `GenerateXmlAsync` is waiting for the UI thread to go back to the message pump so that it can continue working.

Comment: Why are you using a List<Task> anyway? `GenerateXmlAsync` is a single call. Does the actual code work operate on a list of IDs or did you simple mean to write `GenerateXmlAsync(id).Wait();` ?

Comment: The posted code won't even compile. We can't solve issues based on phantasy code snippets.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to load multiple IDs, write a LINQ statement that returns all the items with an ID in the list you want - DON'T load each item individually. This results in delays proportional to the number of items. Specifically, if you try to load 3 individual items it will take 3 times as much as loading the three items in a single query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code blocks on asynchronous code, it's [subject to a deadlock situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). I describe this in full on my blog, but the general gist is:

- When `await` yields the calling thread, by default it first captures a "context". This is usually a UI context (for UI apps), an ASP.NET request context (for server apps), or a thread pool context.
- When the awaitable operation completes, the `async` state machine resumes execution by scheduling itself *to that context*. So, `async` methods on a UI thread will resume on that UI thread, and `async` methods handling an ASP.NET request will resume handling the same ASP.NET request.
- Some contexts (e.g., UI contexts and ASP.NET request contexts) only allow one thread in at a time. So, if there's a thread *blocked* in that context, then the `async` method will wait for that thread before resuming. In this case, the thread is blocked waiting for the `async` method to complete, which it cannot do since it is waiting for the blocked thread. Classic deadlock.

You may also find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post helpful. At the end I have a list of "old blocking ways of doing things" (which should be avoided) along with the "new asynchronous ways of doing things". The relevant example in this case is to replace `Task.WaitAll` with `await Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: That was it, using `WaitAll` was blocking the thread that opened when an I/O op was awaited, which must have started on another thread.  Using `await Task.WhenAll` fixed the issue.  Thanks!